# Unable to summon entity Minecraft 1.13 command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried to summon a zombie with armor as a boss using a command_block. Sadly, this message keep showing up every time I try to summon the zombie:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie -688 26 -433 {CustomName:"\"Killing Machine\"",CustomNameVisible:1,Health:50,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:50},{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:11},{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:0.02f}],DeathLootTable:"mctools:entities/FLower",HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"The Sword Of Death",Lore:["This Sword Will Kill!"]},Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:5},{id:knockback,lvl:2},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:shield",Count:1}],HandDropChances:[2F,0F],ArmorItems:[{tag:{display:{Name:boots},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_boots",Count:1},{tag:{display:{Name:Legs},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:4},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",Count:1},{tag:{display:{Name:Chestplate},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:3},{id:thorns,lvl:3},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]},id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:player_head",Count:1}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:10,Amplifier:0,Duration:400,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

And the same command with the data tag formatted:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie -688 26 -433{  
   CustomName:"\"Killing Machine\"",
   CustomNameVisible:1,
   Health:50,
   Attributes:[  
      {  
         Name:"generic.maxHealth",
         Base:50
      },
      {  
         Name:"generic.followRange",
         Base:11
      },
      {  
         Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",
         Base:0.02f
      }
   ],
   DeathLootTable:"mctools:entities/FLower",
   HandItems:[  
      {  
         id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",
         tag:{  
            display:{  
               Name:"The Sword Of Death",
               Lore:[  
                  "This Sword Will Kill!"
               ]
            },
            Enchantments:[  
               {  
                  id:sharpness,
                  lvl:5
               },
               {  
                  id:knockback,
                  lvl:2
               },
               {  
                  id:unbreaking,
                  lvl:3
               }
            ]
         },
         Count:1
      },
      {  
         id:"minecraft:shield",
         Count:1
      }
   ],
   HandDropChances:[  
      2F,
      0F
   ],
   ArmorItems:[  
      {  
         tag:{  
            display:{  
               Name:boots
            },
            Enchantments:[  
               {  
                  id:protection,
                  lvl:3
               },
               {  
                  id:unbreaking,
                  lvl:3
               }
            ]
         },
         id:"minecraft:diamond_boots",
         Count:1
      },
      {  
         tag:{  
            display:{  
               Name:Legs
            },
            Enchantments:[  
               {  
                  id:protection,
                  lvl:4
               },
               {  
                  id:unbreaking,
                  lvl:3
               }
            ]
         },
         id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",
         Count:1
      },
      {  
         tag:{  
            display:{  
               Name:Chestplate
            },
            Enchantments:[  
               {  
                  id:protection,
                  lvl:3
               },
               {  
                  id:thorns,
                  lvl:3
               },
               {  
                  id:unbreaking,
                  lvl:3
               }
            ]
         },
         id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",
         Count:1
      },
      {  
         id:"minecraft:player_head",
         Count:1
      }
   ],
   ActiveEffects:[  
      {  
         Id:10,
         Amplifier:0,
         Duration:400,
         ShowParticles:0b
      }
   ]
}
```

Have I written something wrong?

Please help.

Comment: Please try shortening that command, it's almost impossible to know what's wing with these super long commands. Also, what have you tried to solve this issue yourself? See also: [help]

Comment: you never told us what message showed up, so we can't determine what's wrong even with the very long code you provided. can you please edit the question giving the error, too?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing the /summon command and saying this:
/summon zombie {wearing Id: diamond_chestplate} {wearing id: diamond_helmet} {wearing id: diamond_boots} {wearing Id: diamond leggings}

There’s your command. You can add the sword stuff to it if you want. I’m not super sure if it will work; I’m kinda new to command blocks too, so... yeah but good luck! :)